# If with multiple &&, || conditions Evaluation in java

Tags: java, if-statement

```
if(a && b || c || d || e)
```

whether it check `(a && b)`, if **a** and **b** must be true always, then only allow inside ? or

`((a && b) || a && c || a && d || a && e))`, any of the condition is true will it allow inside ?

Comment: Why not just `a && (b || c || d || e)`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, in the first part of your question, you are asking whether `a` and `b` must both be true for the entire expression `(a && b || c || d || e)` to evaluate as true.

The answer to that question is no. Java operators are such that `&&` has higher precedence than `||`. So the equivalent expression is:

```
(a && b) || c || d || e
```

Therefore the expression as a whole will evaluate to true if any of `a && b` or `c` or `d` or `e` is true. For example, if `a` was false and `c` was true, the expression as a whole is true.

Note that Java conditional operators short-circuit. This means that once the end result of the expression is known, evaluation stops. For example, if `a` and `b` were both true, meaning the overall expression must evaluate to true, then `c`, `d` and `e` are not evaluated.

For the second part of your question, we can apply the same logic. The equivalent expression is therefore:

```
(a && b) || (a && c) || (a && d) || (a && e)
```

This will evaluate to true if any of the sub-components, eg. `a && c` evaluates to true. As others have noted, `a` must be true for the expression to be true as it is part of every sub-component. Then if any of the other variables is true, the expression is true.

Once you understand that, you can see how the simplification of this expression suggested by @Arc676 is arrived at:

```
a && (b || c || d || e)
```

I should also add that the two expressions in your question are different logically. They are equivalent to:

```
(a && b) || c || d || e
```

and

```
a && (b || c || d || e)
```

The parentheses affect the order of evaluation. In the first, `a` and `b` are grouped together by an `&&`, hence both must be true for that part of the expression (in the parentheses) to be true. In the second, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` are grouped together by `||`. In this case, only one of `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` needs to be true for that part of the expression (in the parentheses) to be true.

Comment: Please jutify this. "For example, if a was false and c was true, the expression as a whole is true". I think that if a false the whole condition is false

Comment: @AbishR No.  The expression is true if `a&&b` is true OR `c` is true (without caring what `a` is) OR `d` is true (without caring what `a` is) OR `e` is true (it still doesn't matter what `a` is).  Since `c` is true, that makes the whole thing true.  Please read dave's answer carefully and look at how he parenthesized the first expression.

Comment: @jb what is the difference between (a && b || c || d || e) and a && (b || c || d || e)

Comment: @AbishR I think my answer is pretty clear. As @ajc points out, the key is that `a && b` acts as a single element with respect to the others. Hence `a && b` or `c` or `d` or `e` must be true for the expression to be true. Hence if `a` is false and `c` is true, the result is true. Can I suggest you write a trivial program with boolean variables exactly as in your example. Test the result for differing values of the variables.

Answer (score 3):

Dave's answer is pretty good. Look there for an explanation.
If you are still having trouble I'll simplify it.

**Case 1:**

```
if(a && b || c || d || e)
```

In this case you can simplify it by saying `z = a && b`
This means that the expression becomes

```
if(z || c || d || e)
```

This is the same as the expression above. `z` is only true if `a` and `b` are true.

**Case 2:**

```
((a && b) || a && c || a && d || a && e))
```

As Arc676 commented, you can simplify it as

```
a && (b || c || d || e)
```

Here you can use the same technique as in case 1 to further simplify it.
If you take `y = b || c || d || e`. Meaning `y` is true if any of `b`, `c`, `d` or `e` are true. Then you can simplify the expression as

```
a && y
```

I'm not saying you should always simplify this but using this technique can make long boolean statements more readable.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thanks @miva2

Comment: Thank you! Note though that you CAN NOT simplify `b || c` in the first example. That would be wrong because `b` is tied to `a` in the first place, not to `c`. You can afterwards combine `z` and `c` though if you want but you can not combine `b` without `a`.

Answer (score 1):

if this is a part of a big code then you'll have to simplify the condition such that the processor will process fast in order to give you an accurate compilation in lesser time.
the most appropriate condition according to me can be " a && (b|| c|| d|| e) " so by using such condition it will just do it in one step rather than going into every condition calling "a" everytime....

for more help you can check on this link and also helps me a lot... Hope you'll get your answer : " http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_if_else_statements.html " .

Answer (score 1):

> ((a && b) || (a && c) || (a && d) || (a && e))

in this one, a has to always be true and either b, c, d, or e has to be true to go in.

> if(a && b || c || d || e)

in this one, a and b have to be true, other wise only c or only d or only e have to be true.

in the snippet it shows that a and b have to be true. if a and b are not true then it can go check if c or d or e are true then it will still be true.

```js
function test(a, b, c, d, e) {

  if ((a && b || c || d || e)) {

    return a;

  }
}
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = " a = 1, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0 answer: " + test(1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = " a = 0, b = 1, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0 answer: " + test(0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = " a = 1, b = 1, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0 answer: " + test(1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = " a = 0, b = 0, c = 1, d = 0, e = 0 answer: " + test(0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Variables</h1>

<p>In this example, a, b, c, d and e are variables</p>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<p id="demo4"></p>
```

Comment: if(a && b || c || d || e)
in this one, as long as one of them is true the statement will be true.  In between there is a '&&' Please say how. If a false in this means how it will execute

Comment: I think the first part of your answer is correct. However, in the second, if `a` *or* `b` is true and none of the others are, then the expression is false.

Comment: Yes @dave. if a and b is true the expresion is true. if a and c is true the expresion true. Am I right?

Comment: @AbishR Correct. Note the expressions are different logically. However for the values you mention, both will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

if(a && b || c || d || e) can be evaluated as both 1 and 2 below :

1 -> if ( a && ( b || c || d || e) )

2 -> if ( (a && b) || (a && c) || (a && d) || (a && e))

Conclusion will be as below :

statement will be true when --> a is true and anyone of b or c or d or e is true

Answer (score 0):

`if(a && b || c || d || e)` stands for:

If `a` is `true` and `b` or `c` or `d` or `e` is true then it will go `inside`. That's it. 
So, if `a` is `true` and at least any rest other variables(`b` or `c` or `d` or `e`) then it will go inside. Otherwise it won't.

Comment: I think that's correct for the second half of the question, but not the first.

Comment: In fact, this answer is just incorrect.  The expression you give, `if(a && b || c || d || e)`, does **not** mean what you say it means.